# How to split the currency value into normal integer

Tags: java, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I have a value `£211,064.10` and i want to convert like `211064.10` and i tried the following way

```
String value = "$107,990.67";       

String abc = value.replace(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency().getSymbol(), "");       
System.out.println(abc);
System.out.println(abc.replace(",", ""));`
```

But it works only for the currency symbol `$` not for any other currency value.

Comment: Yes, because you're asking the system what the LOCAL current symbol is, which in your case will always be `$`. Since the system will never return `€` or `£`, you'll never be looking for/replacing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String abc = value.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
```

Comment: May want to validate the string first. Maybe `value.matches("($|€|£)[0-9]{0,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\\.[0-9]+)?")` or something of the sort

Comment: thanks devnull, so now you gave some regex and its working fine. Could you share some link to learn regex.

Comment: @Lucan A starting point might be [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) too.